# Selenium excepition: Message: element not visible

Tags: python, selenium

I try to open url and fill login and pwd from and open that. I use

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(auth_url)
login = driver.find_element_by_name("login")
login.send_keys(login)
pwd = driver.find_element_by_name("passwd")
pwd.send_keys(pwd)
btn = driver.find_element_by_class_name('button2 button2_theme_action button2_size_m button2_type_submit i-bem')
btn.click()
```

But I get Error

`selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not visible`

`html-code` looks like

`<input class="input__control" id="uniq14963212287341158594" name="login" placeholder="Логин" aria-labelledby="labeluniq14963212287341158594 hintuniq14963212287341158594" aria-required="true"></span></span></div><div class="auth__password"><span class="input input_theme_normal input_size_m i-bem" data-bem='{"input":{"live":false}}'><label class="input__hint input__hint_fallback_yes input__hint_visibility_visible" id="hintuniq14963212287341158595" for="uniq14963212287341158595" aria-hidden="true">Пароль</label><span class="input__box"><span class="input__clear" unselectable="on">&nbsp;</span><input class="input__control" id="uniq14963212287341158595" name="passwd" placeholder="Пароль" aria-labelledby="labeluniq14963212287341158595 hintuniq14963212287341158595" type="password" maxlength="256" aria-required="true"></span></span></div><div class="auth__row auth__row_button_yes"><div class="auth__haunter"><span class="checkbox checkbox_theme_normal checkbox_size_m i-bem" data-bem='{"checkbox":{"live":false}}'><button class="button2 button2_theme_action button2_size_m button2_type_submit i-bem" data-bem='{"button2":{"_tabindex":"0"}}' type="submit" autocomplete="off" tabindex="0"><span class="button2__text">Войти</span></button></div></div><div class="auth__social" role="group" aria-label="Войти при помощи социальной сети"></div><div class="auth__row"><div class="auth__remember"><a class="button2 button2_theme_pseudo button2_size_s button2_type_link i-bem" data-bem='{"button2":{"_tabindex":"0"}}' tabindex="0" href="https://passport.yandex.ru/restoration"><span class="button2__text">Вспомнить пароль</span></a></div><div class="auth__register"><a class="button2 button2_theme_pseudo button2_size_s button2_type_link i-bem" data-bem='{"button2":{"_tabindex":"0"}}' tabindex="0" href="https://passport.yandex.ru/registration"><span class="button2__text">Регистрация</span></a></div></div>`

Comment: Your whole HTML code does not showing any Button word and you have defined `find_element_by_class_name('button2 button2_theme_action button2_size_m button2_type_submit i-bem')`

Please update HTML code

Comment: Please add some wait before interacting with element or add implicitly wait.

Comment: @RNS I have added html code

Answer (score 1):

Add wait time before doing send keys

```
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    driver.set_window_size(1920, 1080)
    wait = WebDriverWait(wd, 10)
    login = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "login")))
    login.send_keys(login)
```

then same for password!!

pls refer this [documentation](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html)

Hope this helps!!

Comment: it returns `selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: `

Comment: As suggested by @wonka could you pls try maximising window size by adding this `driver.set_window_size(1920, 1080)`! I'll update my answer

Comment: some time maximising window will help with finding elements

Comment: it returns `selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:` again

Comment: seems like there is problem in this line `login = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "login")))`!! can you try this `login = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS, "input[name='login']")))`

Comment: I specify `id` of element and now it works, but now i can't click the button, it returns `selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Element <span class="user__enter-label" aria-hidden="true">...</span> is not clickable at point (1007, 33). Other element would receive the click: <button class="button button_size_ml button_theme_normal user__enter header2__button i-bem button_js_inited" data-bem="{&quot;button&quot;:{}}" tabindex="0" type="button" autocomplete="off" title="Войти" aria-label="Войти">...</button>
  `

Answer (score 1):

If the waiting time doesnt SOLVE your problem, sometimes I solved it using this:

```
driver.set_window_size(1920, 1080)
```

Or bigger, I reach to use (4096, 3112)

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that find_element_by_class_name() will work with that full list of class names.  try just specifying one of them.  It looks like this unique in your HTML:

```
btn = driver.find_element_by_class_name('button2_theme_action')
```